# information from table won't show (innerHTML problem)

Tags: javascript, php, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, innerhtml

I'm trying to show the information from my table if user checks the checkbox then clicks on the modal button but it doesn't show. What might be the problem with my script? I tried different ways to solve this but It doesn't really work. The "modal.HTML+="<div..."" does not do anything.

```
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkBtn').click(function(){
      checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length>=1;
      if(!checked){
        alert("You must check at least one checkbox.");
        return false;

      }else{


        var ele=document.getElementsByName["case"];
        var modal=document.getElementById["modaldata"];
            var Name=document.getElementsByName["Name"];
            var Scholarship=document.getElementsByName["Scholarship"];
            var Course=document.getElementsByName["Course"];
            var Semester=document.getElementsByName["Semester"];
            var Status=document.getElementsByName["Status"];
            
            modal.innerHTML="";

**this right syntax? based on what I saw he used this in his sample program.** 
              for (var i = 0 ; i<ele.length; i++){
                if(ele[i].checked==true)
                {
                  modal.innerHTML+="<div class='table-responsive'><table border='1px' class='table' cellspacing='10px'><tr class='info' align='center'><td>Image</td><td>Description</td><td>Price</td></tr><tr><td align='center'><p>'+Name[i].innerHTML+'</p></td><td align='center'><p>'+Scholarship[i].innerHTML+'</p></td></tr></table><div>";
                }
              }

      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You should use paranthesis ('(' and ')') instead of brackets when calling functions. For example: `document.getElementById("modaldata")`. Also [debug your code, or use `console.log(...)`-s](https://www.programiz.com/javascript/debugging) to find out which variables get populated, and if their values are ok.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I appreciate it.